# Right edge of screen hidden (VGA)

Tags: display, vga, display-resolution

I recently got a new monitor, switching from a tv connected via HDMI (borrowed, as my previous one broke), and am using VGA for my home PC for the first time. My problem is that the right edge of the (desktop? Display?) is cut off by the edge of my screen. I cannot see it, although my mouse can move there and windows will put content there when maximised/fullscreen.

I have tried to use system settings, but this region of the screen is hidden at all 3 resolutions available, and I can see no other setting that might help. This issue is only at the right edge of the screen, I can see everything else, so no overscan. I'm using a palit 960, and the cable IS plugged into the card, not the motherboard.

Answer (score 1):

Does the monitor get correctly identified in System Settings > Screen Display? There is also a scale option there in Ubuntu 15.04, I don't remember if that was there in earlier releases.

Failing that, I can't say this will definitely solve your problem, but I know you can alter screen geometry with `xrandr` which I had to do with Crunchbang in a virtual machine.

From a terminal, running `xrandr` bare will list modes and tell you what's currently set. To change screen size you can try for example

```
    $ xrandr --size 1680x1050 &
```

or change mode

```
    $ xrandr --mode 1680x1050 --pos 0x0 --rotate normal &
```

And you can alter the framebuffer size too, perhaps shrink it and reposition. The `man xrandr` page has a few examples.

I think the changes are non-permanent though, I'm not sure where each distribution expects settings to be written.